# String.replaceAll() doesn't work on $

Tags: android

I have a String that represents a dollar amount and am trying to use .replaceAll("$", "") on it to prepare it for use with parseDouble(). However, when I run my app I'm still getting a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "$100.00"` so it seems that for whatever reason, replaceAll() isn't working. Can anyone suggest why?

Here's the block of code affected:

```
public String subtractCurrenciesToString(String value1, String value2){
    String stringValue1 = value1.replaceAll("$", "");
    String stringValue2 = value2.replaceAll("$", "");

    Double currency1 = Double.parseDouble(stringValue1);
    Double currency2 = Double.parseDouble(stringValue2);

    return MoneyFormat.format(currency1 - currency2);
}
```

NOTE: MoneyFormat is a NumberFormat object initialized with getCurrencyInstance().

Comment: For what it's worth if you are doing any calculations with your money values you really should not be using Double to store it. See Here for a great explanation why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Interesting read Foamy, thanks. Still, as long as I'm rounding before storing the data, it avoids the dangers of wildly divergent number errors.

Answer (score 6):

`replaceAll` accepts a regex. In regex, `$` is an end-of-string anchor, so you have to escape it in order to use it literally as a dollar sign:

```
.replaceAll("\\$", "");
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I tried the correction you mentioned and I'm still getting the $ in my String when I parseDouble().